# get most updated parameter (SQL)

Tags: sql

consider the following table:

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|   ID  |   param1  |   param2  |   param3  |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|   1   |   12      |   21      |   1       |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|   2   |   11      |   3       |   22      |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|   3   |   55      |   17      |   22      |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I need an SQL query which gets the value of the most updated (= highest ID) value of a single parameter (for example, if I want the most updated param2 I want the query to return 17).
I must say that I don't have any knowledge in SQL, I just encountered it at work and I need a solution for this specific problem. when I searched for solutions I only found solutions for getting the whole row, I only need a single parameter from it.
thanks.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: just edited, thanks

Comment: highest param2 is 21 and not 17

Comment: you gave wrong example `if I want the most updated param2 I want the query to return 17`

Comment: He wants to get param2 for max id i.e. for id 3 it is 17. 3 is the max id.

Comment: what @TheShooter says :)

Comment: @noamgot: My answer should get you what you want.

Comment: Will the `ID` be duplicated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Param2
FROM tableName
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Oracle:

```
SELECT Param2
FROM tableName
ORDER BY ID DESC
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1
```

PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT Param2
FROM tableName
ORDER BY ID DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: You're fast and I missed by a second. Was going to add this query as an alternate method to my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

quick fix: picked your query @jarlh

```
SELECT param2
FROM tablename
WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tablename)
```

Comment: Perhaps you're correct. I had some problems understanding the question.

Comment: that's it, that's what I needed. simple and elegant. thanks!

Comment: Its not best and elegant the answer given by @Pawel Dyl is the best and elegant. Sorry for saying that but it's not a good way to do simple things in complex way.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple way:

```
select *
from tablename
where id = (select max(id) from tablename)
```

Will return both rows if there's a tie.

Comment: doesn't it returns the maximal param2? I want param to from the row with maximal ID...